# Proof for a marginal distribution

Tags: probability, gaussian-process, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I am reading this paper by Wang and Barber title 'Gaussian Processes for Bayesian Estimation in Ordinary Differential Equations'. Can someone help me with the proof of marginal distribution [image]

Kindly refer the paper for joint distribution at: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/barber14.pdf

Any hint would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Because questions must stand on their own, this one needs (at a minimum) an explanation of the notation in order to be comprehensible.